# Separating unit tests and integration tests in Go

Tags: unit-testing, go, integration-testing, testify

Is there an established best practice for separating unit tests and integration tests in GoLang (testify)? I have a mix of unit tests (which do not rely on any external resources and thus run really fast) and integration tests (which do rely on any external resources and thus run slower). So, I want to be able to control whether or not to include the integration tests when I say `go test`.

The most straight-forward technique would seem to be to define a -integrate flag in main:

```
var runIntegrationTests = flag.Bool("integration", false
    , "Run the integration tests (in addition to the unit tests)")
```

And then to add an if-statement to the top of every integration test:

```
if !*runIntegrationTests {
    this.T().Skip("To run this test, use: go test -integration")
}
```

Is this the best I can do? I searched the testify documentation to see if there is perhaps a naming convention or something that accomplishes this for me, but didn't find anything. Am I missing something?

Comment: I think the stdlib uses -short to disable tests which hit the network (and other longrunning stuff too). Other wise your solution looks okay.

Comment: -short is a good option, as is your custom build flags, but your flags need not be in main.  if you define the var as `var integration = flag.Bool("integration", true, "Enable integration testing.")` outside of a function, the variable will show up in package scope, and the flag will work properly

Answer (score 197):

@Ainar-G suggests several great patterns to separate tests.

[This set of Go practices from SoundCloud](http://peter.bourgon.org/go-in-production/#testing-and-validation) recommends using build tags ([described in the "Build Constraints" section of the build package](http://golang.org/pkg/go/build/)) to select which tests to run:

> Write an integration_test.go, and give it a build tag of integration. Define (global) flags for things like service addresses and connect strings, and use them in your tests.
>
> ```
> // +build integration
>
> var fooAddr = flag.String(...)
>
> func TestToo(t *testing.T) {
>     f, err := foo.Connect(*fooAddr)
>     // ...
> }
> ```
>
> go test takes build tags just like go build, so you can call `go test -tags=integration`. It also synthesizes a package main which calls flag.Parse, so any flags declared and visible will be processed and available to your tests.

As a similar option, you could also have integration tests run by default by using a build condition `// +build !unit`, and then disable them on demand by running `go test -tags=unit`.

@adamc comments:

For anyone else attempting to use build tags, it's important that the `// +build test` comment is the first line in your file, and that you include a blank line after the comment, otherwise the `-tags` command will ignore the directive.

Also, the tag used in the build comment cannot have a dash, although underscores are allowed. For example, `// +build unit-tests` will not work, whereas `// +build unit_tests` will.

Comment: I have been using this for some time now and it is by far the most logical and simple approach.

Comment: if you have unit tests in same package, you need set `// + build unit` in units tests and use -tag unit for run the tests

Comment: It seems the latest version of go have deprecate the `tags` functionality.

Comment: @Tyler.z.yang can you provide a link or more details about deprecation of tags? I didn't find such information. I'm using tags with the go1.8 for the way described in the answer and also for mocking types and functions in tests. It is good alternative to interfaces I think.

Comment: For anyone else attempting to use build tags, it's important that the `// +build` test comment is the first line in your file, and that you include a blank line after the comment, otherwise the `-tags` command will ignore the directive. Also, the tag used in the build comment cannot have a dash, although underscores are allowed. For example, `// +build unit-tests` will not work, whereas `// +build unit_tests` will

Comment: How to handle wildcards? `go test -tags=integration ./...` doesnt work, it ignores the tag

Comment: I'm working with go1.11.4. For separate my unit test and integration test in same package,I have to add different tags for unit_test.go and integration_test.go at the same time,otherwise `go test -tag=integration` will run both test case.

Comment: why have you added an exclamation mark in "+build !unit" ?

Comment: Decided to investigate this approach of using the -short tag + Makefile. I tried build tags approach earlier with VSCode and experienced linting errors from gopls. Checkout https://github.com/golang/go/issues/29202. It appears to be a know issue and it was taking up too much of my time trying to tweak gopls settings to recognise build flags. Furthermore, these settings are global for all go projects. Managed to get linting errors down to 1 problem with go.mod not recognising a package with build flags name and then gave up. Ended up using the -short tag approach below.

Comment: You need to be careful with multiple build tags and their syntax. I encountered unexpected issues when I had a build tag like `// +build unit, !int, !dark`. 
Firstly, don't use comma followed by spaces which leads to unpredictable behavior. Changing the above to `// +build unit,!int,!dark` lead to expected behavior. Furthermore, it was simpler to just have `// +build unit`.

Comment: I m running go 1.15. I followed the instruction above, so I tried to run go test -tags=integration but it's not working. Moreover, the go test help does not mention any parameter -tag.
I named my integration test with TestIntegration_what_it_test and run go test -run TestIntegration and it works!

Comment: How can we work around this when we want to use an IDE, say VSCode, and simply right click the root folder and run all tests, but only want to run the unit tests?

Comment: @jordan well if your IDE doesn't have the feature, you can't use the feature. Can you set up a custom task that VSCode will run for you from a right-click menu?

Answer (score 106):

To elaborate on my comment to @Ainar-G's excellent answer, over the past year I have been using the combination of `-short` with `Integration` naming convention to achieve the best of both worlds.

### Unit and Integration tests harmony, in the same file

Build flags previously forced me to have multiple files (`services_test.go`, `services_integration_test.go`, etc).

Instead, take this example below where the first two are unit tests and I have an integration test at the end:

```
package services

import "testing"

func TestServiceFunc(t *testing.T) {
    t.Parallel()
    ...
}

func TestInvalidServiceFunc3(t *testing.T) {
    t.Parallel()
    ...
}

func TestPostgresVersionIntegration(t *testing.T) {
    if testing.Short() {
        t.Skip("skipping integration test")
    }
    ...
}
```

Notice the last test has the convention of:

1. using `Integration` in the test name.
2. checking if running under `-short` flag directive.

Basically, the spec goes: "write all tests normally.  if it is a long-running tests, or an integration test, follow this naming convention and check for `-short` to be nice to your peers."

### Run only Unit tests:

```
go test -v -short
```

this provides you with a nice set of messages like:

```
=== RUN   TestPostgresVersionIntegration
--- SKIP: TestPostgresVersionIntegration (0.00s)
        service_test.go:138: skipping integration test
```

### Run Integration Tests only:

```
go test -run Integration
```

This runs only the integration tests.  Useful for smoke testing canaries in production.

Obviously the downside to this approach is if anyone runs `go test`, without the `-short` flag, it will default to run all tests - unit and integration tests.

In reality, if your project is large enough to have unit and integration tests, then you most likely are using a `Makefile` where you can have simple directives to use `go test -short` in it.  Or, just put it in your `README.md` file and call it the day.

Comment: love the simplicity

Comment: Do you create separate package for such test to access only the public parts of package? Or all mixed?

Comment: @Dr.eel Well, that's OT from the answer.  But personally, I prefer both: a different package name for the tests so I can `import` my package and test against it, which ends up showing me what my API looks like to others. I then follow up with any remaining logic that needs to be covered as internal test package names.

Comment: @eduncan911 Thanks for the answer! So as I understand here `package services` contains an integration test sute, so to test the APIfo the package as a blackbox we should name it another way `package services_integration_test` it will not give us a chance to work with internal structures. So the package for unit tests (accessing internals) should be named `package services`. Is it so?

Comment: That's correct, yes. Here's a clean example of how I do it: https://github.com/eduncan911/podcast (notice 100% code coverage, using Examples)

Comment: @eduncan911 but here in your reply "Unit and Integration tests harmony, in the same file" it looks like you mixing tests for internals with integration tests in the same scope of `package services`. If it so you can accidentially access internals.

Comment: Correct. That podcast repo is a different concept I have to blog about.  But you were asking about different packages, which you can see in the `examples.go` files that they are different packages.

Comment: Good one. For running only Integration Tests, I had to use go regex ```go test -v -run ".Integration" ./...``` here [go regex](https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/syntax/) and a [good example](https://zetcode.com/golang/regex/)

Comment: Decided to investigate this approach of using the -short tag + Makefile. I tried build tags approach earlier with VSCode and experienced linting errors from gopls. Checkout https://github.com/golang/go/issues/29202. It appears to be a know issue and it was taking up too much of my time trying to tweak gopls settings to recognise build flags. Furthermore, these settings are global for all go projects. Managed to get linting errors down to 1 problem with go.mod not recognising a package with build flags name and then gave up. So using this approach saving frustration for other devs on proj.

Comment: @anon_dcs3spp yep, I strive for zero linting issues on strict and simple Makefiles.  That's why I use this approach. :-)

Answer (score 63):

I see three possible solutions. The first is to use the [short mode](http://golang.org/pkg/testing/#Short) for unit tests. So you would use `go test -short` with unit tests and the same but without the `-short` flag to run your integration tests as well. The standard library uses the short mode to either skip long-running tests, or make them run faster by providing simpler data.

The second is to use a convention and call your tests either `TestUnitFoo` or `TestIntegrationFoo` and then use the [`-run` testing flag](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Testing_flags) to denote which tests to run. So you would use `go test -run 'Unit'` for unit tests and `go test -run 'Integration'` for integration tests.

The third option is to use an environment variable, and get it in your tests setup with [`os.Getenv`](http://golang.org/pkg/os/#Getenv). Then you would use simple `go test` for unit tests and `FOO_TEST_INTEGRATION=true go test` for integration tests.

I personally would prefer the `-short` solution since it's simpler and is used in the standard library, so it seems like it's a de facto way of separating/simplifying long-running tests. But the `-run` and `os.Getenv` solutions offer more flexibility (more caution is required as well, since regexps are involved with `-run`).

Comment: note that community test runners (e.g. `Tester-Go`) common to IDEs (Atom, Sublime, etc) have the built-in option to run with `-short` flag, along with `-coverage` and others. therefore, I use a combination of both Integration in the test name, along with `if testing.Short()` checks within those tests.  it allows me to have the best of both worlds: run with `-short` within IDEs, and explicitly run only integration tests with `go test -run "Integration"`

Answer (score 17):

I was trying to find a solution for the same recently.
These were my criteria:

- The solution must be universal
- No separate package for integration tests
- The separation should be complete (I should be able to run integration tests *only*)
- No special naming convention for integration tests
- It should work well without additional tooling

The aforementioned solutions (custom flag, custom build tag, environment variables) did not really satisfy all the above criteria, so after a little digging and playing I came up with this solution:

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "regexp"
    "testing"
)

func TestIntegration(t *testing.T) {
    if m := flag.Lookup("test.run").Value.String(); m == "" || !regexp.MustCompile(m).MatchString(t.Name()) {
        t.Skip("skipping as execution was not requested explicitly using go test -run")
    }

    t.Parallel()

    t.Run("HelloWorld", testHelloWorld)
    t.Run("SayHello", testSayHello)
}
```

The implementation is straightforward and minimal. Although it requires a simple convention for tests, but it's less error prone. Further improvement could be exporting the code to a helper function.

### Usage

Run integration tests only across all packages in a project:

```
go test -v ./... -run ^TestIntegration$
```

Run all tests (*regular* and integration):

```
go test -v ./... -run .\*
```

Run only *regular* tests:

```
go test -v ./...
```

This solution works well without tooling, but a Makefile or some aliases can make it easier to user. It can also be easily integrated into any IDE that supports running go tests.

The full example can be found here: https://github.com/sagikazarmark/modern-go-application

Comment: Unless I have misunderstood, with this method you can only have one function named TestIntegration in a single file

Comment: Actually, you can have one function per package. You can create multiple functions with different names (eg. TestIntegrationFoo). You would also have to remove the dollar sign from the regex.

Answer (score 6):

I encourage you to look at Peter Bourgons approach, it is simple and avoids some problems with the advice in the other answers: https://peter.bourgon.org/blog/2021/04/02/dont-use-build-tags-for-integration-tests.html

Answer (score 4):

There are many downsides to using build tags, short mode or flags, see [here](https://konradreiche.com/blog/how-to-separate-integration-tests-in-go).

I would recommend using environment variables with a test helper that can be imported into individual packages:

```
func IntegrationTest(t *testing.T) {
    t.Helper()
    if os.Getenv("INTEGRATION") == "" {
        t.Skip("skipping integration tests, set environment variable INTEGRATION")
    }
}
```

In your tests you can now easily call this at the start of your test function:

```
func TestPostgresQuery(t *testing.T) {
    IntegrationTest(t)
    // ...
}
```

Why I would not recommend using either `-short` or flags:

Someone who checks out your repository for the first time should be able to run `go test ./...` and all tests are passing which is often not the case if this relies on external dependencies.

The problem with the [`flag`](https://pkg.go.dev/flag) package is that it will work until you have integration tests across different packages and some will run `flag.Parse()` and some will not which will lead to an error like this:

```
go test ./... -integration
flag provided but not defined: -integration
Usage of /tmp/go-build3903398677/b001/foo.test:
```

Environment variables appear to be the most flexible, robust and require the least amount of code with no visible downsides.

Comment: I think flag.Parse() is not needed inside the test files and can be omitted. See [source](https://blog.jbowen.dev/2019/08/using-go-flags-in-tests/). So I don't see the problem using the flag package.

Comment: @OsmosisD.Jones It will be a problem once some of your packages have integration tests and others do not.

Answer (score 0):

I think all three options presented have some merit.

I agree that build tags can get quite messy, but I think both t.Short() and environment variables are valid options.

I think the one big downside to using environment variabels over t.Short(). Is that you can no longer run a single integration test from IDE testing like VSC. Visual Studio Code will render a "run test" button above a test function and if that is gated behind an environment variable that functionality will no longer work.

This could be solved by using a negative environment variable like
SKIP_INTEGRATION_TESTS, but at that point you might as well use t.Short() as it seems like a cleaner solution in Go.

I think it largely depends on what kind of integration tests you have and what you want the default behaviour to be of a new developer working on this project.
If everything is automated, including dependency setup / seeding (using testcontainers/dockertest or anything like that, you wouldn't have failing tests on `go test ./...` they would just take longer than `go test ./... -short` as they run the full suite.
If you have manual dependency setup steps than maybe it is better to use environment variables.

TLDR: Standard development answer: "It Depends"