# Integration tests, wildcard ignore tags

Tags: testing, go, integration-testing, wildcard

I would like to separate my integration tests from the unit tests. I have read that I can do it including tags in the test file:

```
// +build integration
```

On the other hand, I select all the packages from my project by using wildcards `./...`

Unfortunately, I have problems, tags are ignored because of the wildcard.

```
go test ./... -tags=integration
```

or

```
go test -tags=integration ./...
```

Do you have any solution or alternative to it?

Comment: For the *alternative* part, I'd recommend this great answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41407042/4636715

Comment: Flags usually go before arguments. What happens when you swap `./...` and `-tags=integration`?

Comment: Hi Peter, I get the same result. I tried both and unfortunately, I posted it xD.

Answer (score 1):

Within your integration tests you can use:

```
func Test_SomeIntegration(t *testing.T) {
    if testing.Short() {
      t.Skip("skipping test")
    }
    ...
}
```

And then pass -short flag to the go test command to skip integration tests:

```
go test -short ./...
```

Answer (score 0):

## Update 2021

This Just Works now! But I did run into an issue where ***the tags are ignored if there is a* `TestMain`** function in the file. So if you're having this issue now, check for that. For the record I run with:

`go test -tags="all your tags here" -v -count=1 ./...`

Hopefully this helps someone in the future