# How to create different suites and define their order of execution in Godog?

Tags: go, bdd

I want to create different test suites for execution of my test cases. The main idea is that I want to load some sample data into database using a feature file in a single suite. After this suite is completed I want to execute different suite containing the test scenarios. Is it possible in GoDog?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Separating unit tests and integration tests in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25965584/separating-unit-tests-and-integration-tests-in-go)

Answer (score 0):

There is an example in DATA-DOG repo https://github.com/DATA-DOG/godog/tree/master/examples/db with DB connection it could be helpful. It gives you an opportunity to roll back inserted data before every scenario or suite if you want.